# Динамическое добавление фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment, fragment-transaction, fragment-manager

Подскажите почему введено некорректно? Во многих примерах именно так показывается работа с динамическим управление фрагментов.

`Закрашивается androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction`

```
public class TranslateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EnglishFragment EnglishFrag;
    FragmentTransaction ft;
    JapaniseFragment JapFrag;
    ChineseFragment ChinaFrag;
    RussianFragment RussFrag;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_translate);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    //ошибка на строчке ниже
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    EnglishFragment EnglishFrag = new EnglishFragment();
    ft.add(R.id.Tranlation, EnglishFrag, "fragment1");
    ft.commit();
}
```

}

Comment: скорее всего, вы используете фрагмент (или `FragmentTransaction`) из библиотеки поддержки, а менеджер - обычный. Замените `getFragmentManager()` на `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); Спасибо,  работать стало после такого изменения:) Только вот почему?)Никогда такого не встречал

Comment: потому что классы библиотеки поддержки и классы API - разные классы и взаимно не заменяют друг друга. вы используете фрагменты из библиотеки поддержки, а управлять ими хотите средствами API, смотрите импорты классов